# How to join tables including rows that doesn't find a match by using a non foreign key field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an attendees table with the following structure:

```
+--------------+---------+
| attendee_id  | others1 |
+--------------+---------+
|    abcd      | B       |
|    ghij      | A       |
|    defg      | C       |
+--------------+---------+
```

And also an eventattendees table with the following structure:

```
+--------------+---------+----------+
| attendee_id  | others2 | event_id |
+--------------+---------+----------+
|    wxyz      | D       |     1    |
|    mlno      | E       |     2    |
|    defg      | F       |     3    |
+--------------+---------+----------+
```

What I want is to create a query that, given some event_id, returns a join of these tables (by attendee_id) but also returns rows with attendee table information for the attenddes ids which didn't found a match for that event_id. Say, for event_id 3:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+----------+
| attendee_id  | others1 | others2 | event_id |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
|    abcd      | A       |  null   |   null   |
|    ghij      | B       |  null   |   null   |
|    defg      | C       |    F    |     3    |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
```

How can I do that for mysql?

Comment: this can be done with an outer join.

Comment: you just changed the question after I gave you an answer with the prior data

Comment: Use the updated answer. I have to leave now. You can order by any column if you want.

Comment: question rolled back

Comment: Ok, I leave it there then. So what should I do now if I want an answer to my actual question?

Comment: That was your actual question and you got two answers to it. Create a New Question if you have a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join. The first table should be your main table and the second table returns null if no match found.

```
SELECT a.*, b.others2, b.event_id FROM attendees a LEFT JOIN eventattendees b ON a.attendee_id = b.attendee_id GROUP BY a.attendee_id
```

Test:

```
CREATE TABLE attendees
    (`attendee_id` varchar(10), `others1` varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE eventattendees
    (`attendee_id` varchar(10), `others2` varchar(10), `event_id` int);

INSERT INTO attendees
VALUES
    ('abcd', 'B'),
    ('ghij', 'A'),
    ('defg', 'C');

INSERT INTO eventattendees
VALUES
    ('wxyz', 'D', 1),
    ('mlno', 'E', 2),
    ('defg', 'F', 3);


SELECT a.*, b.others2, b.event_id FROM attendees a LEFT JOIN eventattendees b ON a.attendee_id = b.attendee_id GROUP BY a.attendee_id
```

Comment: But that would include all event ids an I just want event id = 3.

Comment: It should include only event_id 3. Did you provide the correct data?

Comment: Why should it? Your answer doesn't include a clause for event_id, maybe you edited it and had problems when submitting it?.

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori, Maybe I misunderstood your question. You want a result like the 3rd table you provided. right?

Comment: Yes, as you can see, the resulting table should include ALL attendees from the attendee table but only show the eventattendees table information if its event_id is 3.

Comment: @DanielCalderonMori. So, I tried it.
It's working well. I added the queries I tried to my answer.

Comment: I edited the question. Would it work for that eventattendees table?